# sails.js - Need multiple session from same browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, socket.io, sails.js

I am using [sails.js](http://sailsjs.org) and Socket.io for real time location update. Now I want to test my application by creating 50 instance from client side. I am getting the 50 different socket_id in server side from client side, But session remain same for each instance. How can I achieve different 50 session from same client for testing.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about 50 of them, but something like this may work for you:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/multilogin/nccllfnllopfpcbjdgjdlfmomnfgnnbk?utm_source=plus

It's a Chrome app that lets you have multiple sessions.

Comment: Yes. But I want to do that from the javascript code in client side. It will generate 50/100 session via for loop. I found the process of creating socket_id but session stuck me.

Comment: if you run the client script twice from separate terminals do you get two sessions?

Comment: I did not try. I did from chrome browser.